# Create dynamic UCM view on UNIX when VOB on Windows

Tags: windows, unix, clearcase

Is that possible to create UCM view on UNIX side when the VOB and PVOB reside on Windows side?
It seems to be impossible, even with CCFS, since I have to use mkview -stream while the PVOB is not accessible. Please let me know if I wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I confirm it shouldn't be possible (UCM or no UCM).

Vob and PVob should always be on Unix (Unix Vob server) in an heterogeneous environment.
Windows can access Unix (for instance through [samba](http://www.samba.org/) path), the contrary isn't possible or easy to setup.

The only possibility is [through CCRC](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629), ClearCase Remote Client.
Since it is a web server, it should be on a server similar to the Vob server, in order to communicate the ClearCase requests from any client (Windows or Unix) to the Vob server (which would be on the same LAN than the CCRC server)